# Is it possible to use Go to send and receive file descriptors over Unix domain sockets?

Tags: unix, go, unix-socket

In the `unix(7)` man page for Unix domain sockets, it says that `sendmsg` can be used with the `SCM_RIGHTS` flag to send file descriptors over these sockets. Is this supported in Go? Is there any good example code out there showing how it's done?

It appears that there is a [`Msghdr` structure](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Msghdr) declared in the `syscall` package. But no functions take it. Maybe I have to use the raw system call interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a package that does it here: https://github.com/ftrvxmtrx/fd/blob/master/fd.go. However that's using the Syscall package to achieve it. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this with Go standard library API.

In the `syscall` package, the things to look at are `UnixRights`, `ParseUnixRights`, and `ParseSocketControlMessage`. These can be used in conjunction with `Readmsg` and `Sendmsg` to send file descriptors over AF_UNIX sockets.

The basic structure goes something like this for receiving:

```
buf := make([]byte, syscall.CmsgSpace(<number of file descriptors expected> * 4))
_, _, _, _, err = syscall.Recvmsg(socket, nil, buf, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var msgs []syscall.SocketControlMessage
msgs, err = syscall.ParseSocketControlMessage(buf)
var allfds []int
for i := 0, i < len(msgs) && err == null; i++ {
    var msgfds []int
    msgfds, err = syscall.ParseUnixRights(&msgs[i])
    append(allfds, msgfds...)
}
```

And for sending, it's much simpler (`var fds []int`):

```
rights := syscall.UnixRights(fds...)
err := syscall.Sendmsg(socket, nil, rights, nil, 0)
```

Comment: That's good enough for me. This whole thing I'm working on is extremely Linux specific. I've even had to fight a bit to keep it from being x86_64 specific. This UnixRights thing is just the ticket. It should work on anything that implements the Posix API that allows this sort of thing.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to edit the real answer into your answer. Who knows if that code you link to will be there forever?